# Form select for an array attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Usergroup` which has 2 attributes which are arrays:

```
Usergroup.create(name: "Group 1", account_id: 7, hix_modules: ['cs-seh','cs-ddr'], users: [61,83,77])
```

Now I want to create a form to create a usergroup. What is the best way to do this for the array attributes? I'm thinking of using selects combined with either Cocoon or Stimulus in the end to add a variable number of `users` or `hix_modules`. But to start simple with just one fixed select: how does it look like to send a valid array to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

edit your model to make the field serialized to an array

```
 class Usergroup < ActiveRecord::Base
      serialize :hix_modules,Array
      serialize :users,Array
    end
```

test it out in console

```
 a = Usergroup.new
 => #<Usergroup id: nil, hix_modules: [], users: [], name: nil, account_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
 a.hix_modules
 => [] 
 a.hix_modules << "cs-seh"
 => ["cs-seh"]
```

Comment: OK thanks, but how will the form look like? Let's say I want a select field: `f.select :hix_modules, options_for_select(@hix_modules)`

Answer (score 0):

I soled it by using a multi select:

```
= f.select :hix_modules, options_for_select(@hix_modules), { prompt: "Select module" }, { multiple: true, size: 10}
```

This sends these params values:

```
 Parameters: {"usergroup"=>{"account_id"=>"7", "name"=>"Test", "hix_modules"=>["", "CS-Agenda", "CS-DDR"], "users"=>["", "65", "77", "46"]}
```